# align all the buttons together in an html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on designing an html page in which I want to align all textbox and all the buttons in vertical position.

But I am not able to understand how can I align all the buttons on the right side together so far I was able to create Add button.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/) I have got so far. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
#my-text-box {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 585px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h3>Test</h3>
<label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label></br>
<input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button">Add</button>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
<textarea rows="30" cols="80">
some stuff
</textarea>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can make two column in which first will be for inputs and second will be for buttons

Comment: @Amitsingh hmmm, how can I do that? Can you provide an example in jsfiddle for my  understanding?

Comment: use tables with 2 columns as @Amitsingh said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you want to this result than you can some modify your html code and some  css code  as like this

```css
#my-text-box {
    font-size: 18px; /* or larger */
    height: 1.5em; /* or larger */
    width: 585px; /* or larger */
}
textarea{
    width:585px;
    height:300px;
}
.form-section{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:700px;
}
.fleft{float:left}
.fright{float:left; padding-left:15px;}
.fright button{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<h3>Test</h3>


<label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label></br>
<div class="form-section">
    <div class="fleft">
        <input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <button type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
<div class="form-section">
    <div class="fleft">
       <textarea >
        some stuff
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <button type="button">Sort by name</button>
        <button type="button">Sort by value</button>
        <button type="button">Delete</button>
        <button type="button">Show XML</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey are you around? have basic question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style:

```
button {
float:right;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
you can some modify your html code and some css code as like this

<h3>Test</h3>
<label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label></br>
<div class="inputForm">
<input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
<button type="button" >Add</button>
</div>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
<textarea rows="30" cols="80">
some stuff
</textarea>

css are below

#my-text-box {
    font-size: 18px; /* or larger */
    height: 1.5em; /* or larger */
    width: 80%; /* or larger */
}
.inputForm{}
.inputForm input{float:left;}
.inputForm button{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="column1">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label></br>
    <input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
    <textarea rows="30" cols="80">
    some stuff
    </textarea>
</div>
<div id="column2">
    <button type="button">Add</button><br><br>
    <button type="button">Sort by Name</button><br><br>
    <button type="button">Sort by Value</button><br><br>
    <button type="button">Delete</button><br><br>
    <button type="button">Show XML</button><br><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-text-box {
     font-size: 18px;
     height: 1.5em;
     width: 595px;
}

#container {
      width: 1005px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

#column1, #column2 {
     border: 1px solid white;
     float: left;
     min-height: 450px;
     color: white;
}

#column2 {
      padding-top:80px;
      padding-left:10px;
}
```

i also edited your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/2/

Happy Coding...

Comment: How can I also align Sort by name button next to text area to make it exactly look like the way it is in the image?

Comment: Yeah it looks good. One more thing, do you know what is that white color thing in which whole stuff is shown and then we have a blue color background? How can we do that? Any  thoughts?

Comment: just set the body background to whatever color you'd like then make the container div align center.

Comment: Hey are you still around? have basic question. let's chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88972/cssdiscussion)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Simple HTML

HTML

```html
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label>
                <br/>
                <input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label>
                <br />
                <textarea rows="30" cols="71">some stuff</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button type="button">Sort By Name</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button type="button">Sort By Value</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button type="button">Delete</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button type="button">Show XML</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```